# How to create a ViewPager with Tabs and PDFviewer in each Tab?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, androidpdfviewer

How can I create a **viewpager** with **tablayout** each tab containing **pdfviewer** loading a separate pdf file from asset folder.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link to add view pager with TabLayout
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/

Now you can add PDF viewer in each fragment and can load pdf using a variable that will contain the name of pdf inside assets acc to tab.
You can provide value to variable inside `tablayout.setOnTabSelectedListener()` overridden methods and can store in some variable.

Comment: I have about 40 separate PDF files. is it possible to load with one fragment in different tabs?

Comment: then y are your going for tabs? you should go for recycler view. show pdf file name in list form and on click open in pdf viewer. in this way you will have just one Recycler view and one PDF Viewer